# Access to form controls,like openfiledialog from another class

Tags: c#

**I have MainForm with openfileDialog1**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //I tried to return OpenFileDialog like this
    public OpenFileDialog ReturnOpenFileDialog()
    {
        return openFileDialog1;
    } 

  }
```

**and class file Facade.cs**

```
public class Facade
{
   //How can I access to OpenFileDialog1 here?      

       /*Like: 
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "DLL|*.dll";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {....*/
}
```

Namespaces of both files the same,CakeFactory.
How can I access to control OpenFileDialog of MainForm from Facade.cs?

Comment: you should use there result of OpenFileDialog in your facade class, and let your class to process the result

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest define ReturnOpenFileDialog() in a separate utility class and then create instance of that utility class and call this method whenever required.

Another option would be to make ReturnOpenFileDialog() static and then you can call it as MainForm.ReturnOpenFileDialog() in your Facade.cs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormInstances.frm = this;
        new Facade();
    }


    public OpenFileDialog ReturnOpenFileDialog()
    {
        return openFileDialog1;
    }
}
public static class FormInstances
{
    public static Form1 frm { get; set; }
}
public class Facade
{
    public Facade()
    {
       OpenFileDialog f= FormInstances.frm.ReturnOpenFileDialog();
        f.Filter="DLL|*.dll";
        f.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```